# brew php54-xdebug Failed loading xxx.xdebug.so Symbol not found

Tags: php, xdebug

I used brew install php54-xdebug，then I found `php.ini` and added some confs.

```
[xdebug]<br>
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"<br>
xdebug.remote_enable = On<br>
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"<br>
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"<br>
xdebug.remote_port = 9000<br>
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTROM<br>
```

I found this xdebug.so file get through zend_extension, when i tried to use less to open this file content, it pointed out xdebug.so" may be a binary file. See it anyway?

When I used php -a or do some other things about php, it will point out:

> Failed loading
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so: 
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so,
>   9): Symbol not found: _zend_execute_ex   Referenced from:
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so   Expected
>   in: flat namespace  in
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
>   Interactive shell

Comment: I`ve solved this problem . Because I`ve brewed php54-xdebug so it`s no need to point zend_extension path because it already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Find where your xdebug was located:

```
sudo find / -name xdebug.so
```

It will take some minutes.